# Removing empty lines from string array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to get a string array with single words from a textfile. However the array is filled with some empty lines. Any Idea how I can make a string array without those empty lines?

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Quackmatic/f8deb2b64dd07ea0985d/raw/macbeth.txt");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string[] content = reader.ReadToEnd().Split('?', '!', ' ', '\n', '[', ']', '.');

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(content[i]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method overload which takes [`StringSplitOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) as a second parameter with the value `RemoveEmptyEntries`. Then the return value *does not include* array elements that contain an *empty string*.

```
var result = reader.ReadToEnd()
                   .Split(new[] {'?', '!', ' ', '\n', '[', ']', '.'} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

By the way, after this you can call `Trim()` for all elements, because `RemoveEmptyEntries` doesn't consider the string `" "` empty. So you can add this to your code, if you want to discard empty strings:

```
var result = reader.ReadToEnd()
                   .Split(new[] {'?', '!', ' ', '\n', '[', ']', '.'} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Trim())
                   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling `Split`, you can do it with the options as detailed in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28930762/360211). If you were not however and wanted to remove empty lines from an array using linq:

```
content = content.Where(s => s != "").ToArray();
```